# How to scale SVG path with fixed height/stroke-width?

Tags: html, css, svg

It is possible to scale an SVG while keeping its `height` and/or `stroke-width` to a fixed value? I am looking for a way to keep the nice `linecap` rounded and scaled to the defined height (10px, or `stroke-width: 10px`)

Sandbox of what I'm trying to do:
https://codesandbox.io/s/scale-svg-with-fixed-stroke-width-snrh6r

But unsure how to get that to work or if is even possible...

Comment: try [vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect)

Comment: This partially work. Is weird that it doesn't work in the sandbox, however it works in the actual Chrome browser... but the linecap doesn't scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linecaps will expand the width of your `<path>`.

Try this:

- set `width:100%` and `height:10px` for svg
- `preserveAspectRatio="none"` will squeeze the svg/path to the total width of the parent div
- `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` ensures line caps won't be distorted
- the `<path>` is drawn across the entire width
- `overflow:visible` prevents the line caps from being cut off
- `padding:0 5px 0 5px` adjusts the svg viewport by a left and right 5px offset on both sides

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 352px;
  padding: 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.stackbar-svg {
  overflow: visible;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

path {
  stroke: red;
  fill: red;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<div class="App" style="width: 238px;">
  <svg class="stackbar-svg" width="100%" height="10" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path id="stackbar-path-0" class="svgstackbar-color-0" d="M 0 5 L 100 5" />
  </svg>
  <p>As you resize the div, the stroke-width shrink<br>How to keep it at a fixed 10px?</p>
</div>
```

You could make the `<path>` element a 100% width and control

Comment: Oh wow, that `overflow: visible` on the SVG itself was the magic! I had no idea, thank you!